# Is the difference between Angualr's AoT compilation and SSR rendering down to just data bindings?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular2-aot

In `AoT` compilation, the template code is converted to HTML code at the build time itself. In `SSR (using Angular Universal)` also, the final HTML is created before being sent to the browser.

Is the difference then, just that in SSR, the js-equivalent of TS-components are *executed*, which means that the values for any property inside them will be already present (and hence, input elements bound to those properties, would already have their values set in the final HTML sent to the server)?

On the other hand, in a simple AoT-compiled application, the HTML is there but the values bound to their elements are not set (which happens when the js files created from components, are run)

Is that how it happens? If yes, then shouldn't the  tag also get converted into HTML elements when using plain AoT?

Comment: "In AoT compilation, the template code is converted to HTML code" - No, but like this: "The Angular AOT compiler converts your Angular HTML and TS code into efficient JavaScript code" ( https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler ). That code is still run on client-side to render the first and every other view. SSR is not an alternative but an additional technique to further increase performance for first-time visitors and SEO, as the first view is rendered on server side and the client receives that assembled and styled HTML, so there is no need to dynamically render anything at the beginning.

Comment: @MartinSchneider 
1) Typescript code getting converted to Javascript during AoT, I understand, but if HTML is also being converted to js, then it must mean that the HTML would be generated on the client-side using purely js and no actual HTML is sent to the browser. Right? 

2) In the case of SSR however, the entire HTML is constructed first on server and then this HTML is what is directly sent to the browser. Correct?

Comment: That's both correct. Ok, there is actually one index.HTML file sent. But its `<body>` element just contains `<app-root>` where everything is dynamically rendered in, and `<noscript>` to show hint if JS is disabled on client-side.

Comment: Also note that SSR does not replace AOT (or JIT). After the SSR page is loaded, all the other (js, css, etc) files are loaded and enabled, so the full interactivity of the app/website can be established.

Comment: Got it. Then it must mean that in dev environments (where compiler is sent along with the code to browser), the entire HTML template of component is sent along with component's js (pre-converted from ts). In the browser then, the Angular compiler converts the HTML template into equivalent js (i.e. the same thing which it does during the build process in the AoT method)